# CSS :Background color on hover State

Tags: html, css

i  am having left navigation in my web page   See the attached pic to get better idea  of what i have  in design

[image]

as shown in pic i have  15px padding on both sides of  navigation but  problem  is that when i hover over any of   element in navigation its background color should be set to dark grey to the full width  means 15 px padding on both sides must be eliminated on hover state and background color

i really cant get how to solve this  problem on hover state i can add this

```
.nav > li > a:hover { background-color: #f18c2e;
  }
```

but how do i show it full width background color as per given Pic ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `box-shadow` to cover the left and right side (15px offset):

```
nav li:hover {
  background:gray;
  cursor:default;
  box-shadow: 15px 0 0 gray, -15px 0 0 gray;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tn8xC/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: http://jsbin.com/vebopu/2/

Considering the following CSS:

```
/* Your 15px padding */
.nav > li {
  padding: 15px;
}

/* Where you set the initial stuff */
.nav > li > a { 
  background-color: #111; 
  color: #fff;
  display:inline-block;
}

/* You want to remove the padding on li hover */
.nav > li:hover {
  padding: 0;
}

/* But you still want the resulting size to keep the padding */
.nav > li:hover a {
  background-color: #f00;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: that is not working as padding is applied to  its parent container